# Is this the correct way to submit data with multiple submission types on the same page asp.net mvc5

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

So I have a rather large form on one page, but inside that form I have 4 different submission types. Without explaining more about what each form is this is a rough idea.
1: Submit the whole form (creates record for top and bot half)
2: Update a record of the top half
3: Create a record for the bottom half
4: Update a record of the bottom half
So basically I have it set up so that 1 is just a submit button, 2, 3, 4 are all Ajax calls, but to get the data I use Jquery like:

```
$model = {
    'property1': $('#field1').val(),
    'property2': $('#field2').val(),
}
```

Then send it to a Ajax call. Im sure this is not very good since im hardly validating it, does anyone know a better way to handle this?

Comment: @RahulChaudhari A better way to handle submitting different fields on the  same page

Comment: You are using mvc, then at 1st button you are using form method as 'POST' .ok then i think ajax call is the better way to perform another task or mention another buttons and respected form in another form tag with another action method

Comment: @RahulChaudhari Splitting for form up into two forms wont help much, since then I'd have to get all the info when I want to submit for form as a whole (number 1 from my post) and in that situation none of the data will be validated if im collecting it up with Jquery like I have already

Comment: So, ajax call is the better way, and u can check that properties 1&2 are null or not in jquery . if null then alert the error.